# Automapper transform source just temporarily

Tags: c#, database, automapper

I write a generic possibility to convert from database object to business object.

My business object contains custom attributes and depending on them, I like to make specific operations on them. 
On reading from db its quite easy because I can use aftermap (not perfect solution, cause I have to do it by reflection and set the value depending on it)

But on writing back to the database I have to do it beforeMap but this would change the source permanent, but I just like it in a transient way. So do the operation with Source on the fly but do not change source object.

It's a generic option so I can't work with properties.

```
                protected static T MapFromDatabaseWithConversion<T, TSource>(TSource source) where T : MappingModel, new()
            {
                var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TSource, T>().AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.ConvertFromDatabase()));
                return config.CreateMapper().Map<T>(source);
            }
```

Do you have any solution for the check on the fly the attribute of a property and change the value depending on it - or you have any idea to change source only on the fly, so not write the result of source operation to src obj?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to include value tracking in your objects. For each class member you would need a boolean to reflect if the value changed, and a method that checks them all at once such as isObjectChanged().  You can hard code this or wrap your object in a Proxy object at runtime, which is more complicated, but does not clutter you class with value tracking data/methods.  On the other hand, Java Data Objects (https://db.apache.org/jdo/) can do this for you by re-compiling your class files to include value tracking within the class about changing values.  It takes a bit to set up and may be overkill for your specific question, but I have used it many times when targeting multiple data sources in the same project such as a database or spreadsheet.  JDO allows me to use the same code with a different data type manager that can be swapped at runtime.  You can also target a No-SQL database and other data stores as well.